# How to show token value in Webform confirmation

Tags: 7, webforms, tokens

In Webform > Form settings > Submission settings > Confirmation message, how can I show a webform token as part of the confirmation message? Something like:

> Hi `%value[name]`, thanks very much for joining our event!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Webform tokens module](https://drupal.org/project/webform_tokens)

> Webform Tokens provides tokens for user form submissions for forms
>   created with the module Webform 3.

Or upgrade to Webform4 which has this feature inbuilt.